# Convert Bitmap to (Graphics.)path in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I trying to Convert bitmap to a Path in Android 
something like this

```
        Bitmap alpha = bitmap.extractAlpha();
        Path path = BitmapToPath(alpha);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @Dhina17 unfortunately no !

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to draw on canvas like that or do you want to extract the path?
If you want to draw on canvas you can achieve that using porterduff mode

Comment: thank you for your answer but i need to extract the path.